# How can I make a macro to return a value?

Tags: macros, xparse

I want to do something like this:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myCondition}{m}
{
    \ifx <stuff>
        return true
    \else
        return false
    \fi
}
```

And use it like this:

```
\ifx \myCondition{something}
    % do stuff
\fi
```

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Much simpler if you use `\if\condition{something} do stuff \fi`.

Comment: So, how can I make a macro return something? Can I make something similar to programming?

Comment: Macros expand as text.  Even macros used for numerical values are actually the text version of those numbers.  You might try \ifnum instead of \ifx and return 0=0 or 0=1.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all that you want to do then you only need to define a new if-statement:

```
\newif\ifCondition
```

and then just set `\Conditiontrue` and `\Conditionfalse`. In more detail:

```
\newif\ifCondition
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myCondition}{m}
{
    \ifx <stuff>
        \Conditiontrue  % return true
    \else
        \Conditionfalse % return false
    \fi
}
```

and then later you can use:

```
\myCondition{something}% set the \Conditiontrue or \Conditionfalse
\ifCondition% use the condition
    % do stuff
\fi
```

If `\myCondition` is likely to be hidden inside a group you might need to use `\global\Conditiontrue` etc -- although, this really depends on your use-case because, personally, I often find it really useful to be able to make "conditional changes" local to a group.

Comment: Is there a more general/cleaner way?

Comment: @EmilTerman Without knowing more about your actual use-case it's hard to say but I think that it would be cleaner to "do stuff" inside the `\myCondition` macro. This way you don't need the `\ifCondition` at all.

Comment: What If I will need to do `if (\myCondition and \anotherCondition)`?

Comment: With abstract questions without specific details it is always hard to say. Perhaps you need something like the `ifthenelse` package. For the question you asked I'd take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
\if\condition{1}
  do stuff
\else
  do other stuff
\fi
```

You can survive with having

```
\def\condition#1{\relax\relax\fi % this ends the \if test
  \ifx<your tests> % here you put your code to test: \ifnum, \ifmmode, or whatever
    \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname % and this would reopen a new \if test which is true
  \else
    \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname % and this would reopen a new \if test which is false
  \fi}
```

Can't test right now if it works with xparse unexpandable definitions or if they do insert something else. You can use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` to define `\something`.

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\condition{m}{..}
```

Comment: I wonder if you mean `\if1\condition{arguments}%` and the macro `\condition` expands to either 0 or 1, or would that be an altogether other idea?

Comment: That would be other idea, here it does expand to `11\fi<contents and leave a new if open>\iftrue`.